# Some data loss with backup and restore in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have developed and delivered a database-driven application about 1 and half a year ago. During this time, they have backed up database, re-installed software and restored database for a few times. Also they have sent us their database afew times to perform some update to the db structure. They have used the built-in backup and restore capability of the software. The software is using SMO (SQl Server Management Object) to perform backup/restore operations.

They now claim that some of their data has been lost during recent backup and restores.

Is such a claim possible or is just their data entry fault?

I have checked their db manually and data they have been added was not there.

Was there any report on SMO bug?

Comment: It is very unlikely you have found a bug in SMO backup/restore.

Comment: Do they take the application offline when they send you the backup for upgrades? Is it possible that they backed up the DB then made some changes then restored the DB from backup over the existing DB and thus losing their changes?

Comment: Since SMO just calls the TSQL `BACKUP` and `RESTORE` commands, it's highly unlikely that an SMO bug was involved. It's much more likely that this was caused by human error (data entry, time of backup/restore) or a coding error of some sort, like an uncommitted transaction in a script. You'll have to dig into how and when they added the data and made the backup in order to determine what really happened.

Comment: All data operations are done using ADO.NET and connections is closed after any insert pr update. "How can I dig into low"? Is log file backed up and restored along with database itself? Can I find log for very early operations there?

Comment: Do they keep copies of their backups? Perhaps they restored an old backup at some point which would have effectively erased changes between that backup and the later one.

Answer (score 1):

Backup and restore are critical facilities in SQL Server. They always, always, always backup the database consistently (point-in-time). You *cannot* backup or restore in a way that looses a part of the data or introduces other inconsistencies. SQL Server always prevents you from doing that with an error message.

(The myth that data loss might be possible comes from other RDBMSs like MySQL where backups were a challenge a few years ago).

The problem is elsewhere: In the DML executed on the database.

Comment: Software is well-analysed and well-designed and always considered entity consistency. As all you say, there could not be any bug from ourside or SQL Server side.

Comment: I think so. I have had customers doubt data integrity, too, and most of the time they just entered wrong data. This is not an unusual customer complaint.